# How to deal with the <path> stroke width become zero in svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I would like to draw some bezier line.
If the code is like this

```
<path stroke="#F44336" fill="transparent" filter="url(#blurMe)" d="M428.515625 324.5 C 464.2578125 324.5, 464.2578125 324.5, 500 324.5"></path>
```

The height of path become 0.

```css
    html,
    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #fafafa;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    .node {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 12px 18px;
        line-height: 1.6;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    }
```

```html
    <svg id="svg" width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <filter id="blurMe">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="1"></feGaussianBlur>
        </filter>
        <path stroke="#F44336" fill="transparent" filter="url(#blurMe)" d="M428.515625 324.5 C 464.2578125 324.5, 464.2578125 124.5, 500 124.5"></path>
        <path stroke="#F44336" fill="transparent" filter="url(#blurMe)" d="M428.515625 324.5 C 464.2578125 324.5, 464.2578125 224.5, 500 224.5"></path>
        <path stroke="#F44336" fill="transparent" filter="url(#blurMe)" d="M428.515625 324.5 C 464.2578125 324.5, 464.2578125 324.5, 500 324.5"></path>
        <path stroke="#F44336" fill="transparent" filter="url(#blurMe)" d="M428.515625 324.5 C 464.2578125 324.5, 464.2578125 424.5, 500 424.5"></path>
    </svg>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
    <div class="node" style="left: 300px; top: 300px;">hhahahaha</div>
    <div class="node" style="left: 500px; top: 100px;">hhahahaha</div>
    <div class="node" style="left: 500px; top: 200px;">hhahahaha</div>
    <div class="node" style="left: 500px; top: 300px;">hhahahaha</div>
    <div class="node" style="left: 500px; top: 400px;">hhahahaha</div>
```

What is the correct code?

https://codepen.io/bojoyzhou/pen/ObBPxM

Comment: If you want the filter to work, you simply have to endure in some way that the element it applies to never has a width or height of zero.  For example, using @Jacopo's solution.

Comment: Or use userSpaceOnUse units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't have a filter with default units on a horizontal or vertical line. Add an explicit viewBox and fixed unit filter dimensions.

```
    <svg id="svg" width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="730 15 420 450">
    <filter id="blurMe" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" height="500" width="500">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="1"></feGaussianBlur>
    </filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for your code to force the coordinates to have a minimum delta?

for example, if the values have the same y as in your case, force
d from

```
"M428.515625 324.5 C 464.2578125 324.5, 464.2578125 324.5, 500 324.5"
```

to

```
"M428.515625 324.5 C 464.2578125 325.5, 464.2578125 324.5, 500 324.5"
```